# I have a list of df resulting by groupby and I need to add a new column with the frequency of kmers

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a list of pandas data frames that I got applying the groupby function and I want to add to them a new column with the frequency of each kmer. I did that with a loop but I got a message warning that I need to use df.loc[index, col_names].
Here it is a link to one example of the csv file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17vYbIEza7l-1mFnavGGO1QjCjPdhxG7C/view?usp=sharing

```
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
```

The loop works but I wish to have a clean and efficient code to apply.

The list of dfs is like that:

```
  kmers  counts  length
0     A  567623       1
1     C  350724       1
2     G  347436       1
3     T  564242       1
    kmers  counts  length
4      TA  263910       2
11     AT  333672       2
18     TG  241614       2
25     GG  134462       2
32     GC  191060       2
39     CA  241614       2
46     AA  437390       2
59     TT  437390       2
109    GT  183723       2
127    TC  188869       2
197    CG  145046       2
238    CC  134462       2
318    AG  177008       2
336    AC  183723       2
388    GA  188869       2
537    CT  177008       2
     kmers  counts  length
5      TAT   76688       3
12     ATG   60467       3
19     TGG   54513       3
26     GGC   37323       3
33     GCA   64928       3
40     CAA   93670       3
47     AAT  131279       3
53     ATT  131279       3
60     TTA  102674       3
66     TAA  102674       3
72     AAA  164986       3
92     TTG   93670       3
103    GGT   42668       3
110    GTA   46316       3
121    ATC   65235       3
128    TCA   68008       3
156    GTT   68473       3
162    TTT  164986       3
185    GTC   22371       3
191    TCG   37613       3
198    CGT   41831       3
221    CGG   25370       3
232    GCC   37323       3
239    CCG   25370       3
274    TTC   76014       3
280    TCC   32192       3
295    GTG   46545       3
301    TGC   64928       3
312    CAG   40915       3
319    AGC   48577       3
330    CAC   46545       3
337    ACA   54158       3
348    AAC   68473       3
364    ACC   42668       3
382    TGA   68008       3
389    GAT   65235       3
405    GAC   22371       3
416    CAT   60467       3
436    GAA   76014       3
442    AAG   72628       3
448    AGT   45057       3
464    TGT   54158       3
475    TAG   38228       3
481    AGG   32306       3
514    ACG   41831       3
520    CGA   37613       3
531    ACT   45057       3
538    CTT   72628       3
607    ATA   76688       3
613    TAC   46316       3
640    GCT   48577       3
748    CTC   25228       3
836    CTG   40915       3
881    AGA   51053       3
992    CTA   38228       3
1096   CCA   54513       3
1155   GGG   22265       3
1241   CGC   40224       3
1272   GCG   40224       3
1322   TCT   51053       3
1534   CCC   22265       3
1615   CCT   32306       3
2171   GGA   32192       3
3599   GAG   25228       3
```

And I want to do this without the bizarre warning for each grouped df in the list:

```
    [  kmers  counts  length  frequency
 0     A  567623       1   0.310172
 1     C  350724       1   0.191650
 2     G  347436       1   0.189853
 3     T  564242       1   0.308325,
     kmers  counts  length  frequency
 4      TA  263910       2   0.072110
 11     AT  333672       2   0.091172
 18     TG  241614       2   0.066018
 25     GG  134462       2   0.036740
 32     GC  191060       2   0.052205
 39     CA  241614       2   0.066018
 46     AA  437390       2   0.119511
 59     TT  437390       2   0.119511
 109    GT  183723       2   0.050200
 127    TC  188869       2   0.051606
 197    CG  145046       2   0.039632
 238    CC  134462       2   0.036740
 318    AG  177008       2   0.048365
 336    AC  183723       2   0.050200
 388    GA  188869       2   0.051606
 537    CT  177008       2   0.048365,
      kmers  counts  length  frequency
 5      TAT   76688       3   0.020955
 12     ATG   60467       3   0.016523
 19     TGG   54513       3   0.014896
 26     GGC   37323       3   0.010199
 33     GCA   64928       3   0.017742
 40     CAA   93670       3   0.025596
 47     AAT  131279       3   0.035872
 53     ATT  131279       3   0.035872
 60     TTA  102674       3   0.028056
 66     TAA  102674       3   0.028056
 72     AAA  164986       3   0.045083
 92     TTG   93670       3   0.025596
 103    GGT   42668       3   0.011659
 110    GTA   46316       3   0.012656
 121    ATC   65235       3   0.017826
 128    TCA   68008       3   0.018583
 156    GTT   68473       3   0.018710
 162    TTT  164986       3   0.045083
 185    GTC   22371       3   0.006113
 191    TCG   37613       3   0.010278
 198    CGT   41831       3   0.011430
 221    CGG   25370       3   0.006932
 232    GCC   37323       3   0.010199
 239    CCG   25370       3   0.006932
 274    TTC   76014       3   0.020771
 280    TCC   32192       3   0.008797
 295    GTG   46545       3   0.012719
 301    TGC   64928       3   0.017742
 312    CAG   40915       3   0.011180
 319    AGC   48577       3   0.013274
 330    CAC   46545       3   0.012719
 337    ACA   54158       3   0.014799
 348    AAC   68473       3   0.018710
 364    ACC   42668       3   0.011659
 382    TGA   68008       3   0.018583
 389    GAT   65235       3   0.017826
 405    GAC   22371       3   0.006113
 416    CAT   60467       3   0.016523
 436    GAA   76014       3   0.020771
 442    AAG   72628       3   0.019846
 448    AGT   45057       3   0.012312
 464    TGT   54158       3   0.014799
 475    TAG   38228       3   0.010446
 481    AGG   32306       3   0.008828
 514    ACG   41831       3   0.011430
 520    CGA   37613       3   0.010278
 531    ACT   45057       3   0.012312
 538    CTT   72628       3   0.019846
 607    ATA   76688       3   0.020955
 613    TAC   46316       3   0.012656
 640    GCT   48577       3   0.013274
 748    CTC   25228       3   0.006894
 836    CTG   40915       3   0.011180
 881    AGA   51053       3   0.013950
 992    CTA   38228       3   0.010446
 1096   CCA   54513       3   0.014896
 1155   GGG   22265       3   0.006084
 1241   CGC   40224       3   0.010991
 1272   GCG   40224       3   0.010991
 1322   TCT   51053       3   0.013950
 1534   CCC   22265       3   0.006084
 1615   CCT   32306       3   0.008828
 2171   GGA   32192       3   0.008797
 3599   GAG   25228       3   0.006894]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Paulo

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['length'] = df['kmers'].str.len()
df_by_length = df.groupby(['length'])
dfs = [df_by_length.get_group(i) for i in range(1, 9)]
for df in dfs:
    df['frequency'] = df['counts'] / df['counts'].sum()

<ipython-input-142-fd9cfa03968f>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Hope this could help to understand! I got the new table but I would like to use the right code to avoid that warning! I try to use loc and indexes but I was not smart enough to got it done still!

Comment: Please read [ask] and add a [example] to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error related SettingWithCopyWarning. It's important — read up on it [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/). Usually you can avoid it with `.loc` and by avoiding repeat-slicing, but in some cases where you have to slice repeatedly you can get around it by ending `.copy()` to the end of the expression. You can learn when and why this is important via the link. For a more precise answer for how this is emerging from you'll code, you'll need to show us an [MRCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: my code is similar to tdy code. Made a groupby by len, then inside a list compreention i got the list of DFs grouped and then did a loop similar to tdy. Because it is a big csv i tried to use .loc(index, "count").tranform("frequency"). But didnt worked well. Thanks

Comment: This isn’t helpful. We need actual code including sample data in the form of a [example].

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem with the warning just adding .copy() in my list of comprehension like this:

```
dfs = [df_by_length.get_group(i).copy() for i in range(1, 9)]
```

Then:

```
for df in dfs:
    df['frequency'] = df['counts'] / df['counts'].sum()
```

And it solved the warning!

Thanks to you all!

Happy Easter!

Be save!

Paulo